# Sending link through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I was trying to check for a user in the database through ajax. On success it should return a link with the username as the name of the link. Earlier without the link portion everything was working fine but now it displays 'undefined'. Also i know that I am using deprecated `mysql_*` functions and my code is prone to sql injection, but my concern is the above mentioned problem.

This is the php code which is returned through AJAX.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';
require_once("includes/connection.php");
echo '<response>';
$user=$_GET['user'];

if($user==""){
echo "type the username";
}
else{   
$query="SELECT email_id FROM users
    WHERE email_id='{$user}'
    ";
$user_result = mysql_query($query,$connection);
if(mysql_num_rows($user_result)>0){
echo "<a href='friend.php?friend_id=1'> {$user} </a> exists";
    }
else{
                echo "no such user as {$user} exists";
    }
}

echo '</response>';
?>
```

I have not included the function creating the xmlHTTP object but this is the rest of the AJAX code:

```
function start()
{

if(xmlHttp){
try{
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4)
    {
        user= encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("user_input").value);
        xmlHttp.open("GET","search.php?user="+user,true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = mainFunctionHandler;
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }else{
        setTimeout('start()',1000);
    }
}catch(e){
    alert(e.toString());
        }
}
}

function mainFunctionHandler()
{
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
    if(xmlHttp.status==200){
        xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
        xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
        message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
        document.getElementById("divD").innerHTML=message;
        setTimeout('start()',1000);
    }else{
        alert("something went wrong");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: 1. write error_reporting(E_ALL) on the top, 2. check connection is made or not. 3. remove $connection variable from  mysql_query. , if it still not working then put your all connection.php data on the top of above code then check again.

Comment: Before you were returning plain text, and now you are returning an `<a>` tag which is interpreted as an xml node.  Your code for extracting the xml data will have to change.  What are you doing in your ajax success callback function?  Please provide code.

Comment: the connection is made and the ajax is working as it displays the other two msgs. @Noman

Comment: i have included the ajax code above. suggest the corrections. @James

Answer (score 0):

Your client-side JavaScript needs to correctly extract the a tag, and insert it into the main page.

See this example below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="user_input">
<button id="submit" onclick="start()">Search for user</button>
<div id="divD">
</div>
<script>
function start()
{
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
if(xmlHttp){
try{
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4)
    {
        user= encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("user_input").value);
        xmlHttp.open("GET","search.php?user="+user,true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = mainFunctionHandler;
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }else{
        setTimeout('start()',1000);
    }
}catch(e){
    alert(e.toString());
        }
}
}

function mainFunctionHandler()
{
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
    if(xmlHttp.status==200){
        xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
        xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
        message = xmlDocumentElement.innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("divD").innerHTML=message;
        setTimeout('start()',1000);
    }else{
        alert("something went wrong");
    }
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually i m new to ajax. so i not able to understand ur code fully. would u mind checking my ajax code that i have included above. @jeyoor

Comment: @decoder15 I've edited in a working example. The only changes to your code needed were in mainFunctionHandler()

Comment: i changed .firstchild.data to .innerHTML as u mentioned in ur code. but it dindn't work. it still says 'undefined' when a user exists. otherwise works fine. @jeyoor

Comment: Here's an example of my code http://geo.institute/so/test_ajax.html

If the above doesn't help, can you point me to an example of your code? @decoder15